# Can I use a boolean to solve this problem?

Tags: javascript

```
var userInput = prompt();
var alice = String(userInput);
var bob = String(userInput);
if(userInput == alice || bob){

console.log("It is nice to meet you " + userInput);

} else {
    console.log("You are neither alice or bob ");

}
```

write a program that prompts users for a name, and only gives a greeting if the users are Alice or Bob.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not about laziness. It's about the question standing alone, not relying on links. Your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'll edit the question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow :) The best practice here is to try to come off with a solution to a problem, and then asking for help if you get stuck somewhere (being precise at which step you are stuck). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :). On this question it looks like you want us to "do your work" instead of you. Moreover, your question is a bit broad: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Oh trust me, i've tried to come up with various solutions. I'm incredibly frustrated right now and need HELP.

Comment: Your edit tells us to write a program for you, which I'm sure isn't what you want to "ask." Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. In particular, look at what you've learned about the `||` operator and how it works.

Comment: I guess you meant `var alice = "alice";` ...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
    var userInput = prompt();
    var alice = 'alice';
    var bob = 'bob';
    if(userInput == alice || userInput == bob) {
    
    console.log("It is nice to meet you " + userInput);
    
    } else {
        console.log("You are neither alice nor bob");
    
    }
```